# State Plane Coordinate system is off in longitude by almost exactly 5 miles?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, state-plane

I am doing a simple well location map that involves me taking the coordinates from a table (coordinates that are in New York Long Island State Plane 3104), plugging them into Excel and then using the "Find XY" tool on ArcGIS in order to show them visually. The data frame properties have also been set to New York Long Island State Plane. I've downloaded aerial images from a New York State GIS site (https://orthos.dhses.ny.gov/# for those interested). I confirmed both through my boss and Google Earth that according to the coordinates in both decimal degrees and NY Stateplane these images are where my wells are located. However, when I add my aerial images to my map document, the images are shifted in longitude by about 5 miles or so. Latitude wise (Y value) they are correct, but the longitude value (X value) is wrong.

How can I fix this?

I can post pictures and my files as needed.

Comment: Try the feet or meters version of the coordinate system, depending on which you've already tried. If that doesn't work, try the NAD27 version rather than a NAD83 one. A third possibility is that someone dropped the largest digit off the easting values.

Comment: You might want to edit your question with sample coordinates for a well (maybe round to the nearest 10000 if you don't want to share the exact location) plus the same coordinates from the imagery.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-projecting the Aerial Images to Coordinate system "New York Long Island State Plane 3104". Make sure all the data added to Data Frame should be in same Datum.

Comment: The images are downloaded in State Plane 3104; i.e. when I look at their raster properties in ArcCatalog their coordinate system is listed as such.